# Forçar o SSL no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

Digamos que vc utilize o navegador para interagir com a camera do computador ou notebook de alguma forma. Isso só irá acontecer através de uma conexão SSL, pois os navegadores rejeitam a permissão para acessar a camera caso nao seja através do SSL

Como forçar o Rails a sempre usar uma conexão SSL?

Answer (score 2):

Basta ir em /config/environments/production.rb e adicionar o seguinte parâmetro:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```